# Selenium webdriver(Chrome Driver) taking too much time load gmail site due to which testcase fails

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I am trying to automate a scenario, Where i will log into gmail website(my account) and click specific email(our own site) to confirm that email is sent but my problem is that gmail some time takes more than 5 min to load complete because of this the element does not get loaded and when i try to click through css my test case fails.
Gmail loading icon stops after 3-5 min.

**Driver initialization code :**

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("-incognito");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilites = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
        capabilites.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

**Adding force wait :**

```
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
        testingdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(gmail);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
        testingdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(gmail);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
```

**Then Clicking element:**

```
 IWebElement firstEmailOpening =  testingdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tr.zA:nth-child(1)"));
 firstEmailOpening.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This threadsleeps are nightmare, I would strongly advise you against this approach where you are logging into gmail using webdriver. Instead, you could use some libraries for accessing your gmail account, see [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) for details.

Comment: Yeah i know it i will be removing them in near future currently i just want the gamil to load properly even with this much hard coded wait its not completely loading

Comment: Ok, but I'm not talking just about Thread.sleep(), whole concept of logging into gmail using webdriver is pretty bad, if you have some time see those tutorials and try to access your emails in google account using some mail libraries. Good luck in any case. :)

Comment: Sure i will look into it thanks it really helps now i can narrow down my effort.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Implicit wait` Like -

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(gmail);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

It is recommended, do not use `Thread.Sleep(30000);` In such cases suppose you had mentioned wait 30 seconds but your element get visible in 2 seconds . It will wait 28 second extra. It makes your script slow.

If You are facing same issue then use `ExplicitWait`

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("tr.zA:nth-child(1)")));
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tr.zA:nth-child(1)")).Click();
```

Comment: I tried using those 2 also i tried
testingdriver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4));
even this code of line get executed in 2 sec and the site doesnt even get loaded .... though i will look again in explicit wait may be i can work something there

Comment: any error you have faced ? Can yo show up your code ?

Comment: Element not found exception but if i use debugger and wait for certain time in which the loader icon stop the one in favicon and run code it finds the element

Comment: I tried the explicit wait condition but now i am getting following error.
Test_Project.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:40382/session/5a35f5a553d2c5697da02526c6ee1429/element timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: Its look like the element was not loaded and the maximum timeout was 60 sec that's why it was showing error ... I will try other email system to see if this is selenium issue with gmail loading or something else like my latency issue also thanks for the 'explicitwait' advice it helped me understand my issue.

Comment: @Foaud, Its my pleasure, that something is helpful to you